# Cannot 'sudo apt install <something>' after IPtables configuration

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to install some of the packages on Debian VM which is connected to another Debian machine (router). On the router default policy for FORWARD chain is DROP. I added rules for http(80), https(443), ftp(21), ftp-data(20) to ACCEPT but I cannot install anything.

SC: [IPTables configuration on router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrPV6.png)

Default policies on first machine are ACCEPT. When default policy on router is ACCEPT I can reach http://deb.debian.org and install packages.

Comment: Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Pulled from this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211465/which-ports-should-i-open-for-apt-get-to-work)

Allow connections that originate from inside

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps.